# K8s - Cannot access service/clusterIP from another node

Tags: kubernetes, docker-registry

I am trying to access(from worker node) a pod(on worker node) via a service/ClusterIP using `curl http://cluster_ip:port_no` but it isn't working.

Here's some info on service

````
masternode@Master:/localdocker$ kubectl describe svc registry
Name:              registry
Namespace:         default
Labels:            io.kompose.service=registry
Annotations:       kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f docker-compose.yaml -o localregistry.yaml
                   kompose.version: 1.1.0 (36652f6)
Selector:          io.kompose.service=registry
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.100.126.230
Port:              5000  5000/TCP
TargetPort:        5000/TCP
Endpoints:         192.168.171.74:5000
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>```
````

here's some info on pod

```
masternode@Master:/localdocker$ kubectl describe pod registry-7ccd695dc7-69cx4
Name:         registry-7ccd695dc7-69cx4
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         worker/10.0.1.5
Start Time:   Sun, 19 Jul 2020 06:09:14 +0000
Labels:       io.kompose.service=registry
              pod-template-hash=7ccd695dc7
Annotations:  cni.projectcalico.org/podIP: 192.168.171.74/32
              cni.projectcalico.org/podIPs: 192.168.171.74/32
Status:       Running
IP:           192.168.171.74
IPs:
  IP:           192.168.171.74
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/registry-7ccd695dc7
Containers:
  registry:
    Container ID:   docker://ca372f12ef7a1a3cb23e7d6c58337f47848f91212f6c75af6bfd04bc48ea2f27
    Image:          registry:2
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://registry@sha256:8be26f81ffea54106bae012c6f349df70f4d5e7e2ec01b143c46e2c03b9e551d
    Port:           5000/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Sun, 19 Jul 2020 06:09:24 +0000
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:
      REGISTRY_STORAGE_FILESYSTEM_ROOTDIRECTORY:  /data
    Mounts:
      /data from registry-claim0 (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-fhf5k (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             True
  ContainersReady   True
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  registry-claim0:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  registry-claim0
    ReadOnly:   false
  default-token-fhf5k:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-fhf5k
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age   From               Message
  ----    ------     ----  ----               -------
  Normal  Scheduled  13m   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/registry-7ccd695dc7-69cx4 to worker
  Normal  Pulling    13m   kubelet, worker    Pulling image "registry:2"
  Normal  Pulled     13m   kubelet, worker    Successfully pulled image "registry:2"
  Normal  Created    13m   kubelet, worker    Created container registry
  Normal  Started    13m   kubelet, worker    Started container registry
```

This is a practice exercise where I was able to do so(in their live environment) without any NodePorts.

Please let me know if any other info is required.

Answer (score 5):

This is an expected behavior because `ClusterIP` type service is only accessible from within the kubernetes cluster i.e from another pod etc.

If you want to access a pod via a service from outside the kubernetes cluster i.e from the nodes itself then use [NodePort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport) type service.

Once you expose it via `NodePort` service you would be able to access it using `curl http://<NODE-IP>:<NODE-PORT>`

`ClusterIP` is created on service network of the cluster and nodes are in different network. By creating a `NodePort` service a Port is opened in each nodes network to forward traffic to `ClusterIP`. So in essence `NodePort` uses `ClusterIP` internally and is an higher level abstraction built on top of `ClusterIP`.

Comment: So you mean to say, nodes don't become a part of the cluster? Also, why would I then need a clusterIP/service as pods can communicate with each other without NAT? NodePorts are for exposing pod's port to node's external port for public access.

Comment: I can very well use the IP of a pod to communicate between two pods, but I believe if I am using a service it exposes the pods to be used by other nodes and pods.

Comment: Pod IPs change if the pod is restarted which is pretty common in kubernetes ..Service IPs are stable..also creating a clusterIP service gives a DNS based name which can be used to communicate between pods within the cluster.

Comment: I've an exercise where I am supposed to build a local registry on a node and use another node to pull an image out of the registry onto itself. The services have no NodePorts in them :/

Comment: can you please check the question again?

Comment: It's all docker..I don't see any need of kubernetes there

Comment: the commands are docker based but the registry is pod on master ..from which images are being pulled into worker node

Comment: So what is the issue or error again? It's technically not possible to access a pod from outside the cluster using clusterIP..So either the question is wrong or we are misunderstanding it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218165/discussion-between-aakash-verma-and-arghya-sadhu).